# Calculation of block size

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

> A 4KiB, 4-way set-associative cache has a line size of 64 B
>
> in this cache:
>
> The block size (in bytes) is

I tried to calculate it by doing it that way

(line size * line size * sets) / cache size
(64 * 64 * 4) / 4 = 4096

however, that is not the correct answer.

Could someone tell me how to calculate it please?

Comment: What do you mean by "block size".  That's normally synonymous with line size.  Are you maybe trying to calculate the size of each set, associativity times line size?  Or the size of each way?  total size / associativity?

Comment: Squaring the line size doesn't make sense as part of any possible calculation, unless you're also dividing by something that includes a factor of the line size to cancel it out.  The final answer you want is a size, so it has units of bytes.  Not bytes squared.  (It seems you *are* dividing by total cache size in your formula.  cache-size / line-size = number of lines, so you're doing `line_size * sets / num_lines`.  That might mean something, but I'm not sure what off the top of my head.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay I got it. Thanks!